# Generating a random number without duplication issue

Tags: php, arrays, random, numbers, shuffle

I know there are a lot of answers out there on SO about generating random numbers, but I am having problems integrating it with my website.

I am using RANGE to generate a random number and then SHUFFLE. But I am still getting repeated numbers.

Goal: Generate a number between 0-19. Number then corresponds to a specific graphic being displayed.

My code:

```
$numbers = range(0, 19);
  shuffle($numbers);

  print "<div id='commenter-picture'>";
  print "<img src='member_default_" . print_r($numbers[0]) . ".png' />";
  print "</div>";
```

UPDATE: I am using this for comments on my blog when the user is anonymous. So I first check to see if the user is logged in, if they are not then I have this statement to assign the thumbnail to that comment on a blog post. I am not repeating this multiple times in my code, but instead the Drupal CMS is retrieving this code each time there is a new comment.

When I have for example 10 comments listed on a post that is where I am getting repeated thumbnails. That is what I am hoping to eliminate.

Comment: `$numbers`, in this case, will always be an array containing numbers 0 through 19. `shuffle()` just shuffles whatever is already in the array; it does *not* add any new elements. So the resulting array will *never* contain duplicates. I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: You can use `array_pop($numbers)` instead of `$numbers[0]`, so the first number will be removed from the array and will not be displayed again.

Comment: Thanks guys, I updated my question a bit as I am still getting duplicate thumbnails. I guess what is happening is that because the CMS is generating this code each time there is a comment, the random values are constantly having to be re-used?

Comment: Then it is not random and you need to track the use of each number in the DB or somewhere. The chances that a random number repeats every 10 times given only 20 choices is very good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what you mean by "getting repeated numbers".  You do this multiple times on the same page?  Try removing from the array each time with `array_pop()` or `array_shift()`:

```
$numbers = range(0, 19);
shuffle($numbers);

print "<div id='commenter-picture'>";
print "<img src='member_default_" . echo array_pop($numbers) . ".png' />";
print "</div>";

print "<div id='commenter-picture'>";
print "<img src='member_default_" . echo array_pop($numbers) . ".png' />";
print "</div>";

// etc...
```

You might want to loop:

```
$numbers = range(0, 19);
shuffle($numbers);

while($num = array_pop($numbers)) {
    print "<div id='commenter-picture'>";
    print "<img src='member_default_" . $num . ".png' />";
    print "</div>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I updated my question as I am still getting duplicate thumbnails. Maybe this is a larger issue with the CMS?

Comment: Then it is not random and you need to track the use of each number in the DB or somewhere.  The chances that a random number repeats every 10 times given only 20 choices is very good.

Comment: Got it thanks. I'll approve your answer as it answered my initial question. Thanks.